# Is it possible to group S3 events within a certain timeframe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've got a bucket that will receive a random amount of files within an unknown timeframe.
This could be anything from 1 file in 5 hours to 1000 files within 1 minute...

I want to invoke a lambda function when the bucket has new files but I don't really care about the content of the S3 event the lambda gets passed. Is there something that will allow me to call the lambda **a single time** if there a new files within the last 10 minutes without setting up something cron-like that runs every 10 minutes and checks for new files? I really only want to execute this a **single time** and only if there are **new files**.

Comment: Do you mean once every once in a while or ever? I'm wondering what would be your criteria for choosing when to fire the lambda, it would either be time-based or event-based.. unless you add a second lambda (or some other entity) that checks for events and validates against last time the "main" function was executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create a CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) Alarm that monitors the [Amazon S3 request metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html) and fires whenever the number of HTTP PUT requests made for objects in the bucket is greater than zero within a period of ten minutes.